# Emacs - Preserve horizontal position when changing lines

Tags: emacs

Is there a way to make Emacs preserve my cursor's horizontal position, when going up and down between lines of varying widths in a file?

I'll explain what I mean by example. Say I have 3 lines of text:

```
1: ------a
2: --b
3: --c---d
```

Say the cursor is at the position marked above by **a**. If I move down a line, the cursor will be at **b**. If I move down again, it will be at **c**. But I actually want to end up at **d**.

Is there a way to make Emacs do that automatically, so that I can go from **a** to **b** to **d** just by pressing the down arrow twice? Emacs would have to remember my horizontal position from my most recent horizontal movement, and try to restore that horizontal position each time I move vertically.

Comment: Emacs does exactly what you're asking for by default.

Answer (score 1):

Customize user option **`goal-column`** to `nil`.

(You can also use command `set-goal-column` anytime to set `goal-column` to the current column.)

Comment: Do you mean, I should do this, in the .emacs file? *(setq goal-column nil)* It doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Yes. (But better is to use `M-x customize-option goal-column`.) It should do exactly what you described, in most modes. Some modes (such as Dired) make cursor vertical movements always go to a particular column. If it doesn't do what you described, try starting Emacs using `emacs -Q` and then setting it to `nil`. If that works, then recursively bisect your init file to find out what you are doing to counter the behavior.

Comment: I discovered that using this *normal-escape.el* script: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CancelingInEmacs was causing the problem; with that script removed, Emacs's default behavior is actually what I wanted.

Comment: Yeah, I really don't recommend messing with `ESC`.